# "dnf upgrade ..." removes files

Tags: yum, rpm, dnf, software-updates

I have my application in three different `rpm` packages, I wrote its `.spec` file, install works as expected, `dnf remove` deletes the package and also cleans up its config files etc., dependencies are pulled in as required and so on. However I noticed that when doing `dnf upgrade` it does overwrite the old files with new ones (as expected), but also somehow deletes my config files. My understanding is that `dnf upgrade` does not remove first and then installs the package, but just installs new files on top of the old ones. Here is log of `dnf` transaction:

```
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                              1/1
  Running scriptlet: my-app-libs-0.1.0.0-0071.x86_64                              1/1
  Upgrading        : my-app-libs-0.1.0.0-0071.x86_64                              1/6
  Upgrading        : my-app-hooks-0.1.0.0-0071.x86_64                             2/6
  Upgrading        : my-app-0.1.0.0-0071.x86_64                                   3/6
  Running scriptlet: my-app-0.1.0.0-0071.x86_64                                   3/6
  Running scriptlet: my-app-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_64                                   4/6
  Cleanup          : my-app-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_64                                   4/6
  Running scriptlet: my-app-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_64                                   4/6
  Cleanup          : my-app-hooks-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_64                             5/6
  Cleanup          : my-app-libs-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_64                              6/6
  Running scriptlet: my-app-libs-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_64                              6/6
  Verifying        : my-app-libs-0.1.0.0-0071.x86_64                              1/6
  Verifying        : my-app-libs-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_64                              2/6
  Verifying        : my-app-hooks-0.1.0.0-0071.x86_64                             3/6
  Verifying        : my-app-hooks-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_64                             4/6
  Verifying        : my-app-0.1.0.0-0071.x86_64                                   5/6
  Verifying        : my-app-0.1.0.0-0048.x86_6                                    6/6
```

I wonder what does *Cleanup* stage above is doing. And what scripts does *Running scriptlet* actually invoke?

Comment: If you do not want the configuration files to be altered on package upgrade, you would need to [specify those files as configuration files within the RPM spec file](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html).  Files designated with `%config` are not removed on package removal and not replaced on package upgrade.  The cleanup stage would be running whatever scripts you added to `%postun`

Comment: @GracefulRestart, Thanks for feedback. I do have `%config(noreplace)` in front of every configuration file in my `.spec` file, however in `%postun` stage config files are removed. But I expected that `dnf upgrade` would not invoke `%postun` stage at all, just overwrite old files with new ones?

Comment: You can find the order of actions performed during a package upgrade [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#ordering).  There is [an argument passed to the scriptlets](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_syntax) to help distinguish between install/upgrade/remove that you could use.  Without understanding what you are trying to do, I am not sure what other specifics to get into.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers get invoked on installs, upgrades and uninstalls. An 'upgrade' is really an uninstall of the old version, followed by an install of the new version. The triggers have a flag (`$1`) that indicates whether it's an upgrade or not. There's a full description at https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/

I use the following in my spec files:

```
%post
if [ $1 == 1 ] 
then
  # first time install, rather than upgrade
fi

%postun
if [ $1 == 0 ] 
then
  # actual uninstall, rather than upgrade
fi
```